# what does this sql warning mean and how to get rid of it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just ran into a warning. I was wondering what does this warning mean and how can I get rid of it?

```
    Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 10 in /public_html/domain/online.php on line 56
```

Basically its the second time I select time from the user. Here is the code

```
  1st selct - nothing happends - selecting from user_id

  2nd select - selecting from online

  $sql = "SELECT time FROM user WHERE update = 'Online'"; 
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $time = mysql_result($result, 0);
  $update = time() - $time;
```

Its crashes the second time I run a result while selecting the users time. What is that php warning suppose to mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Let's start by showing us your code